# position of first and last non-dot in a string with regex

Tags: regex, r, string

I wish to locate the position of the first and last non-dot elements of a string.  Ideally I would like to do this with `regex` in base `R`.  I have already written `R` code that solves the problem.  However, I am interested in a `regex` solution.  Thank you for any suggestions.

Here is an example data set and the `R` code to obtain the desired result.  This code splits the strings and uses `which` to locate the position of each non-dot.  Then I obtain the `min` and `max` column by row with `aggregate` and `merge`.  However, I suspect `regex` would be much more efficient and much more interesting.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     my.string  state  cov
     11.......    A     1
     111......    A     2
     .1.1.....    B     3
     ....1....    B     4
     ..1.11...    C     5
     ...1.....    C     6
     .........    D     7
     .....1.1.    D     8    
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

new.data  <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(my.data$my.string,'')), my.data[,2:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
new.data2 <- new.data[,1:9]

new.data2[new.data2 == '.'] <- NA

new.data2 <- t(apply(new.data2, 1, as.numeric))

not.NA <- as.data.frame(which(!is.na(new.data2), arr.ind = TRUE))

my.min.max3 <- with(not.NA, aggregate(not.NA$col, by = list(not.NA$row), FUN = function(x) c(MIN = min(x), MAX = max(x)) ))
my.min.max3 <- do.call(data.frame, my.min.max3)
colnames(my.min.max3) <- c('my.row', 'min', 'max')
my.min.max3

my.row <- 1:nrow(my.data)

my.output <- merge(my.row, my.min.max3, by.x=0, by.y = 'my.row', all=TRUE)
my.output <- my.output[,-1]
colnames(my.output) <- c('my.row', 'min', 'max')
my.output

#
#   my.row min max
# 1      1   1   2
# 2      2   1   3
# 3      3   2   4
# 4      4   5   5
# 5      5   3   6
# 6      6   4   4
# 7      7  NA  NA
# 8      8   6   8
#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
> data.frame(my.data[,1], do.call(rbind, gregexpr("^\\.*\\K[^.]|[^.](?=\\.*$)", my.data[,1], perl=T)))
  my.data...1. X1 X2
1    11.......  1  2
2    111......  1  3
3    .1.1.....  2  4
4    ....1....  5  5
5    ..1.11...  3  6
6    ...1.....  4  4
7    ......... -1 -1
8    .....1.1.  6  8
```

Comment: Looks like `\K` is not even documented in the R regular expression docs.  I just ran into the variable length lookbehind issue, so this is pretty interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
minmax <- t(sapply(my.data[,1], function(x) {
                                 y <- gregexpr("[^.]", x)[[1]]
                                 return(c(min=min(y), max=max(y)))}))
minmax[minmax==-1] <- NA

my.output <- data.frame(my.row=1:nrow(my.data), minmax)
#> my.output
#          my.row min max
#11.......      1   1   2
#111......      2   1   3
#.1.1.....      3   2   4
#....1....      4   5   5
#..1.11...      5   3   6
#...1.....      6   4   4
#.........      7  NA  NA
#.....1.1.      8   6   8
```

Comment: Very nice.  Unfortunately, `min` and `max` are `list` 's in your answer.  If `minmax` is converted to a `data.frame` your answer would be perfect.

Comment: Here is the code I used, but there is probably better: `as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(minmax), ncol=2, nrow=nrow(my.data), byrow = FALSE))`

Comment: @MarkMiller, I edited my question and changed the `return` part so now `minmax` is a matrix. so now you just have to do `minmax <- as.data.frame(minmax)` if you prefer it as `data.frame`. (unfortunetly, I don't know how to change the `sapply` call to directly have a `data.frame` as output)

Comment: @MarkMiller, thanks ! I'm glad my solution fulfills your needs :-)

Comment: Although I wouldn't be surprised that @AvinashRaj 's answer got accepted rather than mine. It's more elegant and much more efficient (about 6.5 times more efficient, based on a 20000 rows data.frame)

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I might accept that other answer after all.  I could not quite see how to use the original version, but the revised version of that answer clearly returns the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I would vectorize it using the `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
cbind(my.data[1], with(my.data, 
                       cbind(min = stri_locate_first_fixed(my.string, "1")[, 1], 
                             max = stri_locate_last_fixed(my.string, "1")[, 2])))
#   my.string min max
# 1 11.......   1   2
# 2 111......   1   3
# 3 .1.1.....   2   4
# 4 ....1....   5   5
# 5 ..1.11...   3   6
# 6 ...1.....   4   4
# 7 .........  NA  NA
# 8 .....1.1.   6   8
```